# PHP DOMDocument move nodes from a document to another

Tags: php, domdocument

OK, I'm trying to achieve this for hours now and can't seem to find a solution so here I am!

I have 2 DOMDocument and I want to move the nodes of a document to the other one. I know the structure of both documents and they are of the same type (so I should have no problem to merge them).

Anyone can help me? If you need more info let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To copy (or) move nodes to another `DOMDocument` you'll have to import the nodes into the new `DOMDocument` with [`importNode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php). Example taken from the manual:

```
$orgdoc = new DOMDocument;
$orgdoc->loadXML("<root><element><child>text in child</child></element></root>");
$node = $orgdoc->getElementsByTagName("element")->item(0);

$newdoc = new DOMDocument;
$newdoc->loadXML("<root><someelement>text in some element</someelement></root>");

$node = $newdoc->importNode($node, true);
$newdoc->documentElement->appendChild($node);
```

Where the first parameter of `importNode()` is the node itself and the second parameter is a boolean that indicates whether or not to import the whole node tree.

Comment: How do I loop through all the nodes of a DOMDocument? I tought foreach would work...

Comment: The easiest way would be to use XPath like this: `$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc); $allNodes = $xpath->query('//*');`

Answer (score 2):

You need to import it into the target document. See [DOMDocument::importNode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using this code for unknown structure of document.

```
$node = $newDoc->importNode($oldDoc->getElementsByTagName($oldDoc->documentElement->tagName)->item(0),true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    protected function joinXML($parent, $child, $tag = null)
    {
        $DOMChild = new DOMDocument;
        $DOMChild->loadXML($child);
        $node = $DOMChild->documentElement;

        $DOMParent = new DOMDocument;
        $DOMParent->formatOutput = true;
        $DOMParent->loadXML($parent);

        $node = $DOMParent->importNode($node, true);

        if ($tag !== null) {
            $tag = $DOMParent->getElementsByTagName($tag)->item(0);
            $tag->appendChild($node);
        } else {
            $DOMParent->documentElement->appendChild($node);
        }

        return $DOMParent->saveXML();
    }
?>
```