# Php DOM: when setting nodeValue, code is not formatted, literal HTML tags get displayed instead

Tags: php, html, domdocument, nodevalue

I am trying to replace one of my div's content:

```
  $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHTML($content);

    $elements = $html->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach($elements as $element){
      if($element->getAttribute('name') == "left_0"){
       $element->nodeValue = "<h2>Title</h2>";
     }

echo $html-> saveHTML();
```

I get the following output in my index.php:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
```

I was looking for an answer, but cant find a way to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: you can show content html file or text?

Comment: Index is a simple html5, <html><h2> Title </2></html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a tag with content like: `<h2>Tom</h2>`, `Tom` is the `nodeValue` and `h2` is the `nodeName`.

You cannot write to `nodeName`. To create a new node you will have to use this:

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($content);

$elements = $html->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($elements as $element) {
  if ($element->getAttribute('name') == "left_0") {
    $newElement = $html->createElement('h2','Tom'); 
    $element->appendChild($newElement); 
}
```

If you want to append nested tags, like `<p><h2>Title</h2></p>` you would do:

```
$paragraph = $html->createElement('p');         // create outer <p> tag
$currentElement->appendChild($paragraph);       // attach it to parent element
$heading2 = $html->createElement('h2','Title'); // create inner <h2> tag
$paragraph->appendChild($heading2);             // attach that to the <p> tag
```

Comment: Thanks, and what about outputing multiple nested tags? Like: <div><h2>Title </h2><p> Lorem ipsum... </p></div>

Comment: You would have to remember or retrieve the node you want to attach a new child node to. It's all basically the same: 1. create new: `$newElement = $html->createElement(<name>,<value>);` and then: 2. append it: `$currentElement->appendChild($newElement);`.

Comment: Thanks! One final question, how can I output includes? Like: $content = include 'content.php'.

Comment: @EdmondTamas  Look there about import one document to another - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735857/php-domdocument-move-nodes-from-a-document-to-another

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop change it to:

```
foreach($elements as $element) {
    if ($element->getAttribute('name') == "left_0") {
        $element->nodeValue = null;// removing the text inside the parent element
        $h2 = new \DOMElement('h2', 'Title');// create a new h2 element
        $element->appendChild($h2);// appending the new h2 to the parent element
    }
}
```

If you would like to create nested HTML elements, you will be making your way up from the last child by creating new `DOMElement` for each child and parent and appending each child to its parent. For example:

`<div><h2>H2<h2/></div>`

You would put this inside your loop:

```
$parentDiv = new \DOMElement('div', null);// the outer div
$childH2 = new \DOMElement('h2', 'H2');// the inner h2 tag
$parentDiv->appendChild($childH2); // append the h2 to div
$element->appendChild($parentDiv); // append the div with its children to the element
```

And yeah when you are outputting you should use [`$html->saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and what about outputing multiple nested tags? Like: <div><h2>Title </h2><p> Lorem ipsum... </p></div>

Comment: @EdmondTamas Just updated my answer, Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks! One final question, how can I output includes? Like: $content = include 'content.php'.