# How to delete all nodes from DOMDocument except custom ones?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, xpathquery

I have a DOMDocument in PHP and I'm trying to delete all nodes except of a container with a specific ID.

Lets say I have the following DOM Document:

```
<section>
  <div id="first-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="second-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sub-section">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="third-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

My PHP Code:

```
$domDocument = $this->domParser->loadHTML($markup);

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$nlist = $xpath->query("//*[@id='sub-section']");

$domDocument->saveHTML();
```

With this code I query the correct container. But how could I remove all nodes except this node from my document, so that in the end I have the following nodes:

```
<div id="sub-section">
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
</div>
```

**What I tried**

I tried to go the reversed way with a query like this: `"/*/*[not(@id='test')]"` But it works not fine for nested HTML structures. Sometimes, depending on the structure, it removes all nodes.

Whats the way to go here?

Comment: So I could pick the one I need with `$element = $domDocument->getElementById($id)` and how could I create a new document? `$newDocument = new \DOMDocument();` and `$newDocument->appendChild($element);` gives me: `Uncaught DOMException: Wrong Document Error`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735857/php-domdocument-move-nodes-from-a-document-to-another may help.

Comment: you need to traverse the dom tree vertically. Get all nodes in the document. Traverse each node and mark the one where your element is present. Delete the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That logic is strange. How do you know then what to keep? What in a nested case?

I would pick the ones I need and copy to a new document.

#### Clone a node to a new document

```
$xml = <<<'_XML'
<section>
  <div id="first-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="second-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="sub-section">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="third-section">
    <ul>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
_XML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($xml);

$newDoc = new DOMDocument();
$newDoc->appendChild($newDoc->importNode($doc->getElementById('sub-section'), true));

echo $newDoc->saveHTML();
```

#### Extract only one node

When you only need just one node, you can even easier go with

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($xml);
echo $doc->saveHTML($doc->getElementById('sub-section'));
```

#### Output

The same output with both examples.

```
<div id="sub-section">
      <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
```

#### Demo

https://3v4l.org/ttTS6

Comment: Thanks! `$doc->saveHTML($doc->getElementById('sub-section'));` seems not to be of type DOMDocument. How could I handle this last challenge? In the function I need to call it needs to be a DOMDocument..

Comment: This will happen when `$doc->getElementById('sub-section')` will return null, namingly that element was not found.